# Get last value from pandas groupeddataframe, summed by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
x = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    'FirstGroupCriterium': [1,1,2,2,3],
    'SortingCriteria': [1,1,1,2,1],
    'Value': [10,20,30,40,50]
  }
)
x.sort_values('SortingCriteria').groupby('FirstGroupCriterium').agg(last_value=('Value', 'last'))
```

The latter outputs:

| FirstGroupCriterium | last_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 50 |

What I would like to have, is to sum up the last value, based on the last SortingCriteria. So in this case:

| FirstGroupCriterium | last_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **10+20 = 30** |
| 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 50 |

My initial idea was to call a custom aggregator function that groups the data yet again, but that fails.

```
def last_value(group):
  return group.groupby('SortingCriteria')['Value'].sum().tail(1)
```

Do you have any idea how to get this to work? Thank you!

Comment: just change `first` into `sum`? `x.sort_values('SortingCriteria').groupby('FirstGroupCriterium').agg(last_value=('Value', 'sum'))`

Comment: Hi, in that case, also the Group 2 is aggregated to 70 and does not stay at 40, which is what I want. I only want to sum if the last SortingCriteria value occurs multiple times in the dataset.

Comment: I know I could create another groupby based on FirstGroupCriterium and SortingCriteria and merge it back to my original dataframe, but that sounds like a workaround to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by both columns first, then filter last rows per `FirstGroupCriterium` in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = x.sort_values(['FirstGroupCriterium','SortingCriteria'])

df1 = df[df['SortingCriteria'].eq(df.groupby('FirstGroupCriterium')['SortingCriteria'].transform('last'))]
print (df1)
   FirstGroupCriterium  SortingCriteria  Value
0                    1                1     10
1                    1                1     20
3                    2                2     40
4                    3                1     50
   
   
df2 = df1.groupby(['FirstGroupCriterium'],as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
print (df2)
   FirstGroupCriterium  Value
0                    1     30
1                    2     40
2                    3     50
```

Anoter idea is aggregate `sum` by both columns and then remove duplicates with keep last row by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['FirstGroupCriterium','SortingCriteria'],as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
         .drop_duplicates(['FirstGroupCriterium'], keep='last'))
print (df2)

   FirstGroupCriterium  SortingCriteria  Value
0                    1                1     30
2                    2                2     40
3                    3                1     50
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would require 2 groupbys. So its virtually the same as
`merged = x.sort_values('SortingCriteria').groupby(['FirstGroupCriterium','SortingCriteria']).agg(last_value=('Value', 'sum'))` and then
`pd.merge(x, merged, left_on=['FirstGroupCriterium', 'SortingCriteria'], right_index=True).groupby('FirstGroupCriterium').agg(last_value=('last_value', 'last'))`

Correct?

Comment: @LukasHestermeyer - agree. I add another solution with one `groupby`

Comment: thanks. That looks clean :-) In my case, I have to do some further aggregations for only the FirstGroupCriterium, so I guess I won't get around 2 groupbys, but you have answered the question really well, so I accepted it. Thank you!